# Pinescript - I would like to have a absolute var of SuperTrend direction in this time

Tags: pine-script

I would to know if SuperTrend is long or short (direction <0 or >0) but in this moment, so in real time, or maybe a candle ago. If I need to check just direction to make an action, well that action will be in the past also, in the time SuperTrend changed. For example:

```
if (direction > 0)
    // Crea un'etichetta solo sull'ultima candela
    var labelHandle = label.new(na, na, "", color=color.new(#999999, 0), textcolor=color.white, size=size.small, style=label.style_label_left)

    // Aggiorna l'etichetta ad ogni tick
    label.set_xy(labelHandle, bar_index, STupperBand)
    label.set_text(labelHandle, str.tostring(((STupperBand) * 1), '#') + "")
    
if (direction < 0)
    // Crea un'etichetta solo sull'ultima candela
    var labelHandle2 = label.new(na, na, "", color=color.new(#999999, 0), textcolor=color.white, size=size.small, style=label.style_label_left)

    // Aggiorna l'etichetta ad ogni tick
    label.set_xy(labelHandle2, bar_index, STlowerBand)
    label.set_text(labelHandle2, str.tostring(((STlowerBand) * 1), '#') + "€")
```

I have two labels on the last two directions, but I need to show only the last direction label. As it is dynamic, when trend changes on the hystoric graph the relative condition for direction is satisfied so both are shown, the last one and the previous one.

Thank you very much for your support

Answer (score 0):

```
//@version=5
indicator(title="SuperTrend", overlay = true)
[STBand,direction]=ta.supertrend(4,10)
var labelHandle = label.new(na, na, "", color=color.new(#999999,0), textcolor=color.white, size=size.small, style=label.style_label_left)
if (direction > 0)
    // Crea un'etichetta solo sull'ultima candela
    // Aggiorna l'etichetta ad ogni tick
    label.set_xy(labelHandle, bar_index, STBand)
    label.set_text(labelHandle, str.tostring(((STBand) * 1), '#') + "")    
if (direction < 0)
    // Crea un'etichetta solo sull'ultima candela

    // Aggiorna l'etichetta ad ogni tick
    label.set_xy(labelHandle, bar_index, STBand)
    label.set_text(labelHandle, str.tostring(((STBand) * 1), '#') + "€")
```